# How does find procedure work in python

Tags: python

I wish to create a 'find' procedure **myself**, which is capable of finding a sub-string in a string and it also should be able to read a string backward and give position of match- just like the original find function in python.

I am unable to figure out what logic should I use- also I don't know how the original find functions?

I just started to use python and am fairly new to programming as well.

Any guidance shall be highly appreciated!

Comment: Read a string backward? I'm not sure I understand

Comment: The built-in function is: http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find

Comment: @LevLevitsky, for example if we wish to search a sub-string 'you are awesome.' in the string 'If you can code, you are awesome.' It should give the value 17 since the substring starts at the seventeenth position. But if I wish to find THE LAST OCCURRENCE of our substring 'you are awesome' then it would be specially helpful! :-D

Comment: @NathanVillaescusa, Thanks for the website! Woohoo its awesome for future references. But I wish to create such a function **myself** - for better understanding :-)

Comment: @AbrarKhan Ah, I see. But `find` doesn't do it. There is another method called `rfind` that does what you need.

Comment: @LevLevitsky Oh Goodness! You are right! rfind does work in a smarter manner!
Can you explain the logic it might use?

Comment: @AbrarKhan I posted an answer, but it's very simplistic. Implementing exactly what those methods do is more tricky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that returns all the hints in a list, and `rfind` is defined using the original `find` keyword `backwards`. You can use for integers or floats also. You can easily modify it in order to return only the first hint.

```
def find( x, string, backward = False, ignore_case = False ):
    x      = str(x)
    string = str(string)
    if ignore_case:
        x = x.lower()
        string = string.lower()
    str_list = [ i for i in string ]
    x_list   = [ i for i in x      ]
    if backward:
        x_list.reverse()
        str_list.reverse()
    x = ''.join(x_list)
    string = ''.join(str_list)
    lenx = len(x)
    ans = []
    for i in range( len(str_list) - lenx ):
        if x == string[i:i+lenx]:
            ans.append( i )
    return ans

def rfind( x, string, ignore_case = False):
    return find( x, string, backward = True, ignore_case = ignore_case )

print  find('f','abcdefgacdfh')
# [5, 10]
print rfind('f','abcdefgacdfh')
# [1, 6]
print  find(12,'aaa3331222aa12a')
# [6, 12]
print rfind(12,'aaa3331222aa12a')
# [1, 7]
```

Answer (score 3):

> also I don't know how the original find functions

A good way to learn about functions without googling is to use [Ipython](http://ipython.org/)and especially the [notebook variant](http://ipython.org/notebook.html/). These allow you to write python code interactively, and have some special features. Typing the name of a function in Ipython (either notebook or the interpreter) with a question mark returns some information about the function e.g

```
find?

Type:       function
String Form:<function find at 0x2893cf8>
File:       /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/mlab.py
Definition: find(condition)
Docstring:  Return the indices where ravel(condition) is true
```

Typing two question marks reveals the source code

```
find??

Type:       function
String Form:<function find at 0x2893cf8>
File:       /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/mlab.py
Definition: find(condition)
Source:
def find(condition):
    "Return the indices where ravel(condition) is true"
    res, = np.nonzero(np.ravel(condition))
    return res
```

You would then need to go down the rabbit hole further to find exactly how find worked.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple solution to this problem, however there are also much faster solutions which you may want to look at after you've implemented the simple version. What you want to be doing is checking each position in the string you're search over and seeing if the string you're searching for starts there. This is inefficient but works well enough for most purposes, if you're feeling comfortable with that then you may want to look at Boyer-Moore string searching, which is a much more complex solution but more efficient. It exploits the fact that you can determine that if a string doesn't start at a certain point you may not need to check some of the other positions.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into it :) I am still not convinced how it will enable me to find the sub-string though...
Apparently I can't vote up this answer since 'Vote Up requires 15 reputation'

Answer (score 1):

I think [Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16092297/1258041) means something like this:

```
def find(s, sub):
    for i, _ in enumerate(s):
        if s.startswith(sub, i):
            return i
    return -1

def rfind(s, sub):
    for i in range(len(s)-1, -1, -1):
        if s.startswith(sub, i):
            return i
    return -1
```

This, however, is simpler than the regular `str.find` and `str.rfind` because you can't provide `start` and `end` arguments.

Comment: Yeah! It makes sense, I think I need to practice more, using python :)

Answer (score 1):

```
'mystring'.rindex('my_substring')
```

this returns the first position of the substring, beginning from the right side

```
'mystring'.index('my_substring')
```

does the same thing, but beginns searching the string from the left hand side.

Comment: Thanks So much! I really appreciate for your valuable feedback! Thanks!!

Comment: I seriously do want to... as I mentioned earlier, but I can't since my reputation is 13 :P and you need 15 reputation to vote.... I did select your answer though...

Comment: If you can upvote my question- I can then upvote your post! :-)